# Test config file - newbee issues

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jasmine, js-test-driver

I am trying to setup Jasmine in IntelliJ IDEA with the jasmine-jstd-adapter plugin for JSTestDriver.

- JSTD Plugin is installed
- jasmine was npm-installed globally (so it resides in %APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\jasmine)
- jasmine.js file from the npm install was added to JS libraries in the
  IDEA settings with global scope.
- I have the following package structure inside IDEA:

  ```
  -myProject\

  -- .idea\ {...}

  -- myTest.js

  -- myTest.spec.js

  -- test.jstd

  -External Libraries\

  -- jasmine\

  --- jasmine.js
  ```

Now I have no idea how to structure my config file.
Currently it looks like this, because the Jetbrains help did tell me so:

```
load:
  - "lib/jasmine/jasmine.js"
  - "lib/jasmine-jstd-adapter/JasmineAdapter.js"
  - "*.js"

test:
  - "*.spec .js"
```

But it fails to open the jasmine scripts, when executing the JSTD run configuration:

```
Cannot read C:\Users\danie\Documents\ExercismProjects\javascript\simple-cipher\lib\jasmine\jasmine.js derived from lib/jasmine/jasmine.js
Cannot read C:\Users\danie\Documents\ExercismProjects\javascript\simple-cipher\lib\jasmine-jstd-adapter\JasmineAdapter.js derived from lib/jasmine-jstd-adapter/JasmineAdapter.js
```

**My questions:**

1. Don't I have to add the jasmine-jstd-adapter.js as well somewhere? Where do I find it?
2. How do I load the library files? They are obviously not in \lib\, because there is no lib folder. So how do I refer to the "External Libraries"?
3. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**. you can use `Add Jasmine JsTestDriver adapter` inspection to download the adapter:

- enable `Add JsTestDriver assertion framework support` and `Add Jasmine JsTestDriver adapter`in `Settings | Editor | Inspections JavaScript | JsTestDriver`.
- re-open the project - you will see prompts to download the adapter:

[image]

- hit `Alt+Enter`, specify the folder to download `jasmine.js` and `jasmineAdapter.js` to, press **Add**

  **2**. There is no way to use IDE **External libraries** here - the latter are only used by the IDE itself for code completion/type hinting and are not available to **JsTestDriver** test runner. Library files have to be placed in your project and referenced in `"load"` section using URLs relative to configuration file. Note that http urls are also supported - see https://code.google.com/archive/p/js-test-driver/wikis/ConfigurationFile.wiki

Note that WebStorm will download the library for you if you follow the steps described above